# Automatically input form based on the HOME team in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, forms, oracle-apex

I want the form of ARENA automatically to be input based on the home team. There are 2 tables below. ARENA in Game table is the same to CITY in TEAM TABLE, and it can be identified by HOME team and vice versa. Now what I want to do is that when HOME team is input in the form(see the picture), then ARENA is also input automatically. I wrote the code in SQL code in the shared component in Property editer:

```
select city 
from team 
where name = :P8_HOME;
```

[image: page maintain game in oracle apex]

[image: ]([![The form of maintaining game]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fshZC.png)

GAME table

```
GAME_ID - NUMBER
GAME_DATE - DATE    
ARENA -VARCHAR2(20)
HOME - VARCHAR2(30)
AWAY - VARCHAR2(30)
HOME POINT - NUMBER 
AWAY POINT - NUMBER
```

TEAM table:

```
TEAM_ID - NUMBER    
NAME - VARCHAR2(30)   <- same to HOME and AWAY of GAME table
PREFECTURE - VARCHAR2(20)
CITY - VARCHAR2(20)    <- same to ARENA of GAME table
ADDRESS - VARCHAR2(30)  
POSTAL_CODE - VARCHAR2(10)
```

List Of Value of shared component is:
LOV_ARENA

```
select team_id, city 
from team
order by team_id;
```

Comment: Hi aha, did you still need help with this or did Littlefoot's answer help?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work well. If you have any idea, please help me

Comment: Before I attempt a solution, let me point out some things... 1) There's a difference between a city and an arena. A city can have more than one arena. I recommend adding an ARENA table with a CITY column. Then you could add ARENA_ID to TEAM and GAME. If it's NULL on GAME (the default), look it up through the home team's ARENA_ID value. This would allow you to override the arena a game is played in by just specifying a value in GAME.ARENA_ID. You could probably move the other address related fields to the new ARENA table.

Comment: 2) The GAME table has HOME and AWAY as VARCHAR2s. However, these should be numeric FKs pointing back to TEAM, no? That would eliminate the comment on TEAM.NAME "<- same to HOME and AWAY of GAME table". A team's name is simply their name.

Answer (score 0):

If Arena depends on home team, then its List of Values query should refer it as

```
select team_id, city 
from team
where team_id = :P8_TEAM_ID   --> this
order by team_id;
```

Also, set `P8_TEAM_ID` to be Arena's **parent** item.